# Using UTF-8 for MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

If it is assuming that one-byte characters do not work properly for the Unicode characters, what we need to pay attention to before using UTF-8 in MySQL?

Comment: I have never met problem about number of bytes with string functions with mysql in real projects. What function do you worry about? what language do you plan to use?

Answer (score 0):

There are no single-byte 8-bit encoding in utf8.  All are 2, 3, or 4 bytes long.

For example, is your data containing a single-byte 8-bit encoding such as hex E9 for an é instead of the 2-byte hex C3A9?  In that case you need to say your client has "latin1" by saying `SET NAMES latin1`, or the equivalent in your client language.

If you have C3A9, then you need `SET NAMES utf8`.

Your table needs to have `CHARACTER SET utf8` either on the table or the column(s).

If this does not address your question, please elaborate.

A lot more discussion is found in [my charset blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll).